# Postgres: UPDATE a boolean column that sets all other booleans in that column to false

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering if I can do this in one query

Usecase: twitter pinned tweet. You can have at most one pinned tweet and setting a new pinned tweet, unset all the other previously pinned tweets.

Any ideas?

Comment: `update my_table set boolean_column = (condition);` e.g. `update tweets set pinned = (tweet_id = 666);`

Comment: Note: the pinned property is an attrribute of the *tweep*, not of the *tweet*. (it is generally a bad idea to make the values inside a table to depend on (the presence) other rows) so: `table tweeps (... ,pinned_tweet bigint references tweets(id), ...)` This guarantees that no more than one tweet can be pinned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
UPDATE tweets
SET pinned = NOT pinned
WHERE id = 1234 OR pinned = TRUE;
```

Or to be extra cautious

```
WHERE (id = 1234 AND pinned = FALSE) OR (pinned = TRUE AND id <> 1234)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's a great idea. Though I think it still needs `WHERE id = 1234 OR pinned = TRUE` it to use indexes instead of trying to work on all the rows.